# (Python) MainWindow background image with two overlapping images

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a my main window have a background image. The problem I'm running into is that the background is comprised of 2 separate images. the top image is placed in the center above the bottom image. I can't find any references on how to accomplish this. I'm thinking I might be able to utilize these two methods to do it, but I'm not sure if I'm heading in the right direction or not.

```
QGraphicsScene.BackgroundLayer
QGraphicsScene.ForegroundLayer
```

I'm using python3 with pyqt5. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I wasn't able to find much of anything on this so far.

Thanks in advance.

-edit: In case there is confusion, I have to use 2 images because the background is generated from 2 pictures that are scraped from the web during run time. Maybe someone knows of a way to dynamically merge the 2 images together with specific x,y coordinates with a library, then just use the new image as a background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The easiest way to accomplish what I'm trying to do is to make 2 labels. 1 that covers the entirety of the window, and another that covers the area where the second picture is supposed to go. Then use Pixmap on each label to cast an image to each label. Figure out the x,y offset required to line up the inner image, adjust the label placement, done.

Comment: An answer to your original idea is the `Image.paste(im,box)` method of the pillow package, https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste , which is something you should know about.  But for the specific use case, letting qt do the pasting in display memory seems about as good.

Comment: I was aware of PIL, however I'm trying to use as few libraries as possible. So if pyqt5 was capable of doing the same job, I wanted to do that instead. I appreciate the response though :)